# How to set Eloquent relationship on default User Model

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I am unable to set up eloquent relationship on the default User model.Spare table has a foreign key which is UserID referencing User table. Following is the code

User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->type; // this looks for an admin column in your users table
}
public function spares()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Spares');
}
```

}

Spare.php

```
 public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

SearchController.php

```
 public function index(Request $request)
{

    $spares=Spares::with('user','model')
        ->where ('description','LIKE','%'.$request->searchName.'%')
        ->paginate(5);
    return View::make('browse')->with('spares', $spares);

}
```

browse.blade.php cannot access {{$spare->user->name }}

```
@foreach($spares as $spare)

<tr>
<td class="col-md-6">
<div class="media">
<a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <img class="media-object"
         src='{{ asset("images/spares/$spare->imagePath") }}'
          tyle="width: 100px; height: 100px;padding-left: 10px"> </a>
<div  class="media-body"  style="padding-left: 10px;">

<h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#">{{$spare->description}}</a></h4>
<h5 class="media-heading"> by <a href="#">{{$spare->user->name }}</a></h5>
</div>
</div>
</td>

<td class="col-md-1 text-center"><strong>Rs. {{$spare->price}}/=</strong></td>

</tr>
```

@endforeach

following is the error

[image]

Comment: what is the name of the 'spares' table exactly, and what is the name of the user id foreign key column?

Comment: spares table is 'spares' in that foreign key is 'retailer_id' which references the User table

Comment: That's probably the problem. In the case of `belongsTo()`, Eloquent assumes the column name to be the snake_case variant of the method name, suffixed with `_id`. So that would be `user_id`. To override this, do `return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'retailer_id');` inside Spare.php.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Comment: thanks Jeffrey . :) it worked

Comment: Glad I could help you out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reply to your comment:

> spares table is 'spares' in that foreign key is 'retailer_id' which
>   references the User table

From [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse):

Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id. However, if the foreign key on the  Spare model is not user_id, you may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the belongsTo method:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'retailer_id');
}
```

However, it's probably better to make Eloquent just succeed in resolving your relation without any override when not necessary. One way is to rename your method in Spare.php:

```
public function retailer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Another would be to leave that method as is and rename the foreign key column name to `user_id`. But you'll of course lose the semantics of the word `retailer` in this case.